# How to combine 2 java codes in android studio

Tags: java, android

im little student in Android   Studio.
It works when it's separate, but it doesn't work when it's together.
this is two parts of LoginTwoResult.java

-first part

```
TextView TextView_getID;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.logintwo_result);

    TextView_getID = findViewById(R.id.TextView_getID);
    // 4. 값 넘겨 받기
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    // 5. extra로 넣은걸 extras로 추출 후 정의
    Bundle bundle       = intent.getExtras();
    String ID           = bundle.getString("ID");
    String PassWord     = bundle.getString("PassWord");

    TextView_getID.setText(ID + "님 환영합니다");
}
```

-second part

```
private BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView; //하단바 선언
private FragmentManager fm; //
private FragmentTransaction ft;
private Frag1 frag1;
private Frag2 frag2;
private Frag3 frag3;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

    bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavi);
    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.action_car:
                    setFrag(0);
                    break;

                case R.id.action_home:
                    setFrag(1);
                    break;

                case R.id.action_person:
                    setFrag(2);
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    frag1 = new Frag1();
    frag2 = new Frag2();
    frag3 = new Frag3();
    setFrag(1);         // 첫번째로  뜨는 화면 선택
}
    //프레그먼트 교체 실행
private void setFrag(int n)  {
    fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    switch (n) {
        case 0:
            ft.replace(R.id.main_frame, frag1);
            ft.commit();
            break;

        case 1:
            ft.replace(R.id.main_frame, frag2);
            ft.commit();
            break;

        case 2:
            ft.replace(R.id.main_frame, frag3);
            ft.commit();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

-error event log

```
6:59    Emulator: emulator: ERROR: VkCommonOperations.cpp:525: Failed to create Vulkan instance.
6:59    Gradle build finished in 11 s 447 ms
6:59    Install successfully finished in 2 s 359 ms.
6:59    Emulator: Process finished with exit code 0
7:01    Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project C:\Users\qurater\AndroidStudioProjects\HowCardemo
7:01    Emulator: emulator: ERROR: VkCommonOperations.cpp:525: Failed to create Vulkan instance.
7:01    Gradle build finished in 14 s 65 ms
7:01    Install successfully finished in 1 s 541 ms.
7:02    Emulator: Process finished with exit code 0
```

I'd appreciate it if you could tell me how to combine them.
Thanks

Comment: do you have two on create methods in one activity? And what is exactly what you want to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for your comment MadMax,
These are two different java files. Sorry for confusing you.
first  part bring id  and password from another login activity. 
second part is for bottom nagivation view with 3fragments. 

and i want to know how i can deliver id and password to one of my frag in form of text.

Thank you.